# Clickable Link in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, hyperlink, uialertview, apple-push-notifications

is it somehow possible to add a clickable link to the alert-message of an UIAlertView?
Especially in case of a Push-Notification?

The only solution i see, is to add the link as dictionary-item to the push alert message.
If the message arrive with the link and the app is opened hereupon, i can check wheter there is a link in the dictionary and open a webview.

Answer (score 4):

While adding customizations to a `UIAlertView` is strongly discouraged by Apple, the only way you have is to extend the `UIAlertView` class itself, adding the link as a subview, handling it later in the appropriate way.

Since this is not the right approach, you should consider changing the way the user interacts with the interface.

Comment: In case of an incoming push-notification there is no way to extend the UIAlertView View. Am i right?

Comment: You're right, so you really should revise the way that the user interacts with the notification. Probably you can ask the user if he wants to be redirected to the url or not, and if the answer is yes you automatically load the URL. Just an idea.