# hyperlink in alertbox in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios5

i am developing iPad5 application. 
In my application i want to show hyperlink and onclick that link should open in safari.

I searched.
 but i didn't get  appropriate solution for this.
please help me.

thanks in advance.
for alert i am using:
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"confirmation" 
                                                message:@"some string and hyperlink here" 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];

Comment: please see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949927/clickable-link-in-uialertview

adding a hyperlink to a UIAlertView is strongly discouraged

Answer (score 1):

for this you can add button as subview in alert and make it as hyperlink(custom button with blue text color) and on click on it you can open that link in safari.

thanks